# Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause en consulta a MySQL desde API hecha en Nestjs y TypeORM

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, nestjs, typeorm

Me encuentro realizando una API REST en Nestjs y TypeORM, trabajo con base de datos MySQL. Me viene trabajando perfecto, sin embargo, me han solicitado hacer una ruta para una consulta en la cual intervienen dos tablas. Por rapidez no le hice realaciones y que tuve ciertos problemas y no tengo mucho tiempo para hacerlo, en fin. Opte por hacer dos consultas una completa a una tabla y otra a otra y posteriormente uno lo que necesito por medio de sus id. Sin embargo, cada vez que hago algo el endpoint me devuelte el siguiente error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'"
}
```

Les dejo los aprtes del código que utilizo en el controller y el service para ver que estoy haciendo mal.
***Certificados.controller.ts***

```
  @Get('certPendientes')
  getCertificadosPendiente() {
    return this.certificadosService.getCertificadosPendiente();
  }
```

***Ceritificados.service.ts***

```
async getCertificadosPendiente() {
    const certificados = await this.certificadorepository
      .createQueryBuilder('cert')
      .select([
        'cert.id',
        'cert.id_cliente',
        'SPACE(255) AS Cliente',
        `CASE
            WHEN cert.tipo_solicitud = 'P' THEN 'Paz y Salvo'
            WHEN cert.tipo_solicitud = 'S' THEN 'Certificado de Saldo'
            ELSE 'Tipo Desconocido'
        END AS tipo_descripcion`,
        'cert.fecha AS fecSol',
        `CASE 
            WHEN cert.estado = 'P' THEN 'En Proceso'
            WHEN cert.estado = 'R' THEN 'Rechazado'
            WHEN cert.estado = 'T' THEN 'Terminado'
            WHEN cert.estado = 'V' THEN 'Vencido'
            ELSE 'Tipo Desconocido'
        END AS estado_descripcion`
      ])
      .getRawMany();

      const clientes = await this.clienteRepositroy
      .createQueryBuilder('cli')
      .select(['cli.id', 'CONCAT_WS(" ", IFNULL(cli.nombres, ""), IFNULL(cli_apellidos, "")) AS cliente'])
      .getRawMany();

    certificados.forEach((cert) => {
      if (cert.id_cliente !== null && cert.id_cliente !== undefined && !isNaN(cert.id_cliente)) {
        const cliente = clientes.find((cli) => cli.id === cert.id_cliente);

        if (cliente) {
          cert.cliente = cliente.cliente;
        }
      }
    });

    return certificados;
  }
```

Para finalizar y aclarar, si hago la consulta en MySQL me devuelve bien los datos, todas las columnas itenen datos, estoy probrando con dos usuarios que tiene id y cruzan con id_cliente en la tabla de certificados.

Agradezco comentarios.

NOTA: Después de publicar mi pregunta, hice pruebas, aún tengo el error, les dejo un código más reducido sin cruzar nada que hice para ir probando y les dejo mi entity para que vean que datos tiene la tabla:

service:

```
async getCertificadosPendiente() {
    return this.certificadorepository.query(`
      SELECT cert.id, cert.id_cliente, SPACE(255) AS Cliente,
        CASE 
          WHEN cert.tipo_solicitud = 'P' THEN 'Paz y Salvo'
          WHEN cert.tipo_solicitud = 'S' THEN 'Certificado de Saldo'
          ELSE 'Tipo Desconocido'
        END AS tipo_descripcion, cert.fecha AS fecSol,
        CASE 
          WHEN cert.estado = 'P' THEN 'En Proceso'
          WHEN cert.estado = 'R' THEN 'Rechazado'
          WHEN cert.estado = 'T' THEN 'Terminado'
          WHEN cert.estado = 'V' THEN 'Vencido'
          ELSE 'Tipo Desconocido'
        END AS estado_descripcion
      FROM certificados cert
    `);
  }
```

Y acá esta el certificados.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity('certificados')
export class Certificado {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: '' })
    tipo_solicitud: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: '' })
    estado: string;

    @Column({ type: "date" })
    fecha: Date;

    @Column({ type: "date", nullable: true })
    fechadescarga: Date;

    @Column({ type: "date", nullable: true })
    fechavencimiento: Date;

    @Column({ type: "date", nullable: true })
    fechaentrega: Date;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: '' })
    ruta: string;

    @Column({ default: 0 })
    id_cliente: number;

}
```

Comment: El único error que veo es que `cli_apellidos` debería ser `cli.apellidos`, pero eso no debería generar el error que mencionas.

Comment: Sí, yo me percate cuando estaba creando la pregunta y la corregi en mi código, sin embargo, no me afecta en nada, el error me sigue saliendo. Muy amable por el comentario.